# How to pass several PHP variables using a HTML link and do not refresh the page?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, hyperlink

I have some code:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

Then I want to call another page inside index.php?page=

```
if($page == "view_data") 
{
  include "view_data.php";
}
else if($page == "edit_data")
{
  include "edit_data.php?id=";
}
else if($page == "delete_data")
{
  include "delete_data.php?id=";
}
else
{
  echo "Cannot found the page";
}
```

I then make a link to generate an `if` function above.

```
<a href="index.php?page=edit_data&id=<?= $row['id_data'] ?>">Edit</a>
<a href="index.php?page=delete_data&id=<?= $row['id_data'] ?>">Delete</a>
```

My problem is how to pass the edit data or delete data if I have to use 2 variables in my link so that edit and delete data can execute only one page?

Comment: Please clarify: You want to pass the `page` values `edit_data` and `delete_data` using just one link and make your script include the edit_data.php and delete_data.php?

Comment: just one link with many data according to data id

Comment: And what would be the result of editing and deleting data in the same iteration? If you edited first, it would then be deleted. If you deleted first, there would be nothing to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `ajax` in your client-side:

```
function doAction(page,id)
{
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert(response);//if you want to notify the user that the job was done successfully
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?page="+page+"&id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

And your HTML will be using the `onClick` attribute

```
<button onclick="<?php echo "doAction(\"edit_data\",".$row['id_data'].")"; ?>">Edit</button>
<button onclick="<?php echo "doAction(\"delete_data\",".$row['id_data'].")"; ?>">Data</button>
```

The rest of your `PHP` code can remain unchanged